# Redirecting a broadcast to multicast using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, ip, broadcast, multicast

Does anyone have experience with this or does anyone know if it can even be done? I know I can stream a saved video file to a UDP IP address, and I know I can take a video stream and save that on to my linux machine but how can I do both at the same time?

I could write a script to save the video from the broadcast coming in and then afterwards multicast that to whatever UDP IP I need, but I can’t afford any lag between the feeds, just a couple seconds at most. Is there a way that I can do this concurrently?

Comment: If the work is just forward some packets, why bothering ffmpeg? You can write some simple C codes or use iptables for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple program with a loop that starts waiting for UDP packets and sends their contents to the multicast destination (or use a tool like [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html)).

Note that the TTL has not the same meaning in unicast and multicast packets, so you will have to set the TTL according to the multicast threshold rules:

- 0: Restricted to the same host. Won't be output by any interface.
- 1: Restricted to the same subnet. Won't be forwarded by a router.
- <32: Restricted to the same site, organization or department.
- <64: Restricted to the same region.
- <128: Restricted to the same continent.
- <=255: Unrestricted scope. Global.

You do not specify the programming language you want to use, but note that the socket interface is available with most of programming languages, so you could use it to program that loop.

For instance, with Java, you would use a java.net.MulticastSocket instance instead of a java.net.DatagramSocket instance, since only MulticastSocket let you set the TTL using `public void setTimeToLive(int ttl)`. Such a method does not exist with DatagramSocket.

Anyway, without programming, you can use the **socat** command line tool this way:

We suppose you are listening on port 1234 and want to send the data flow to the multicast destination 224.0.2.3 on the same port:

```
% socat UDP4-RECV:1234 UDP-SENDTO:224.0.2.3:1234,ip-multicast-ttl=128
```